# Cannot push to git from windows/phpstorm

Tags: git

My repository is on Bitbucket. I have a Ubuntu machine that I use as a development server (which hosts a local copy of all my code, apache, php, git etc). The actual development is done on a Windows machine in the same LAN. I use a Samba share to access the files on the server directly.
I use PHPStorm as my IDE. I installed git on the Windows machine as well, in order to use git integration in PHPStorm. And it works: I can read the repository history and commit new changes withouth problem.

But now I want to push (to bitbucket) from PHPStorm as well. And that is what fails.

Right now, I need to login to my Ubuntu server to push code from there. But I'd like to be able to psuh from PHPStorm. It has probably to do with ssh-keys I need to integrate, but I don't know how. PHPStorm tells me the following:

```
19:22:10.873: git push --progress origin master:master
java.io.IOException: Authentication failed: 
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.authenticate(SSHMain.java:283)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:157)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:137)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already created a SSH key pair and put the public key on Bitbucket. I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Does PHPStorm have access to the private key and have you instructed it to use the key for authentication?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [PhpStorm git Integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-git-integration.html) man page does mention:

> - ssh keys are generated outside PhpStorm. You can follow the instructions from http://inchoo.net/tools/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-git-authorization/ or look for other guidelines.
> - Store the ssh keys in the home_directory `\.ssh\` folder. The location of the home directory is defined through environmental variables:
>
>   - `$HOME` for Unix-like operating systems.
>   - `%userprofile%` for the Microsoft Windows operating system.
> - Make sure, the keys are stored in files with correct names:
>
>   - `id_rsa` for the private key.
>   - `id_rsa.pub` for the public key.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great tutorial :) I followed a wrong one apparently.

Comment: If you use multiple keys you can pair it up with `%userprofile%/.ssh/config` to specify which key you want to use for which server.

Comment: Just a heads up for those who change the desktop folder path: PHPStorm will look for the SSH keys in the <parent folder>/.ssh

Answer (score 14):

If your git commands work from the commandline, but not from inside WebStorm, you could try switching your WebStorm configuration to use "**Native**" instead of the "**Built-in**" SSH executable.

To do this, navigate the menus for **Files -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git** and then change the **SSH executable** dropdown setting to "**Native**."

Comment: Weird... Git commands work from the commandline, not inside phpStorm. BUT I had to switch from "Built-in" to "Native" !! And now it works...
All in all, you helped me x)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the native SSH executable option in PhpStorm & linked to `plink.exe` provided with PuTTY, you will need to connect to the host server at least once to accept the server's host key. Once the key is cached you can then add your Private key into `pageant.exe`

```
plink.exe git@github.com
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) y
Using username "git".
Server refused to allocate pty
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: this was key to my success! but, I am using builtin, it still craps out on native. I have determined that JetBrains is using putty or some version of it as its built in.

Comment: Question: `if you are using the native SSH executable option in PhpStorm & linked to plink.exe` **How do you tell JetBrains to use plink.exe as the native ssh client?**

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. My ssh keys were perfectly fine as I was using them with Git Bash (Windows).

I deleted known_hosts from **C:\Users\Your User Name\.ssh** folder and PHPStorm created it on its own and it started working.

On my another project, it was giving following error:

```
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 158.xxx.xxx.xxx::22
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:791)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:577)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:137)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 158.xxx.xxx.xxx:: invalid IPv6 address
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1169)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.createInetAddress(TransportManager.java:165)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.establishConnection(TransportManager.java:340)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initialize(TransportManager.java:449)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:731)
    ... 3 more
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And it turned out the remote url of my GIT project was set wrong:

```
ssh://myuser@myip:/home/user/myrepo
```

should be:

```
myuser@myip:/home/user/myrepo
```

Comment: where did you change this?

Comment: You can change it using this command: git remote set-url origin user@ip:/your_repo